# Stripping Filename in PHP

Tags: php, rename

I'm building a version control system in PHP.  I almost have a fully working system and am currently adding features. My code below renames a file as "filename_Ver 0.01" and increments by .01 if the user selects a minor revision from the html selectbox. If it's a major revision, the file gets renamed as filename_Ver 1 and increments by 1 for each major version. If I combine both, let's say a major and a minor revision I end up with a file named "filename_Ver 1.01.ext"

Displaying the filename in a PHP table is easy enough but I'd like to optionally just display the version number say in a seperate table field called "Version". How would I strip that from the filename so I can add that to the database? I know I'd have to do something within the while loop to get what I want out. `$file = $dr.$fName.'_'.'Ver '.$i.$ext;` I want it to display something like the following:

```
FileName | Version
test_Ver 0.1 | 0.1
test_Ver 0.2 |  0.2
test_Ver 1   |  1
test_Ver 1.1 |  1.1
```

```
function update_file_name_major($file) 
{
  $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
  $ext = substr($file,$pos); 
  $dir = strrpos($file,'/');
  $dr  = substr($file,0,($dir+1)); 

  $arr = explode('/',$file);
  $fName = substr($arr[(count($arr) - 1)], 0, -strlen($ext));

  $exist = FALSE;
  $i = 1;

  while(!$exist)
  {
    $file = $dr.$fName.'_'.'Ver '.$i.$ext;

    if(!file_exists($file))
      $exist = TRUE;

    $i++;
  }

  return $file;
}
function get_file_name_major_latest($file) 
{
  $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
  $ext = substr($file,$pos); 
  $dir = strrpos($file,'/');
  $dr  = substr($file,0,($dir+1)); 

  $arr = explode('/',$file);
  $fName = substr($arr[(count($arr) - 1)], 0, -strlen($ext));

  $exist = FALSE;
  $i = 1;

  while(!$exist)
  {
    $file = $dr.$fName.'_'.'Ver '.$i.$ext;

    if(!file_exists($file)){
      $exist = TRUE;
      return $i;
    }

    $i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
function update_file_name_minor($file, $latest_major = 0) 
{
  $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
  $ext = substr($file,$pos);
  $dir = strrpos($file,'/');
  $dr = str_replace(end(explode("/",$file)), '', $file); 

  $arr = explode('/',$file);
  $fName = current(explode(".",end(explode("/",$file))));

  $exist = FALSE;
  $i = (float) $latest_major. '.01';

  while(!$exist)
  {
    $file = $dr.$fName.'_'.'Ver '.$i.$ext;

    if(!file_exists($file))
      $exist = TRUE;

    $i += 0.01;
  }

  return $file;
}

if ( isset( $_POST['addfile'] ) ) {

// variables
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'repository/'); 
$fileName = $_FILES['file'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$projectname=$_POST['projectname'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];

if($_POST['rev_type'] == 'Minor') {
// check for which action should be taken if file already exist
if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $fileName['name'])) 
{
    $latest_major = 0;
    if(update_file_name_major(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']) != UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']){
        $latest_major = get_file_name_major_latest(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);
        --$latest_major;
    }
  $updatedFileName = update_file_name_minor(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name'], $latest_major);
  move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], $updatedFileName);

    include 'db.php';
    $updatedFileName2 = update_file_name_minor($fileName['name'], $latest_major);   
    $add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `myversions`(filename, filetype, projectname, comments, created) 
    VALUES ('$updatedFileName2', '$file_type','$projectname','$comments', NOW())");

  echo "You have successfully uploaded and renamed the file as a minor revision.";
}
else
{
  move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);

 echo "You have successfully uploaded the file.";
  }
}

elseif($_POST['rev_type'] == 'Major') {
// check for which action should be taken if file already exist
if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $fileName['name'])) 
{
 $updatedFileName = update_file_name_major(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);
  move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], $updatedFileName);

include 'db.php';
    $updatedFileName2 = update_file_name_major($fileName['name']);
    $add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `myversions`(filename, filetype, projectname, comments, created) 
    VALUES ('$updatedFileName2', '$file_type','$projectname','$comments', NOW())");

  echo "You have successfully uploaded and renamed the file as a major revision.";
}
else
{
  move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);

 echo "You have successfully uploaded the file.";
    }           
  }         
} //main if
```

Comment: Consider using regex, something like /Ver ([0-9]+)/

Comment: You are already using `explode` in your function to increment the next version number. It seems trivial to use the same method to print the version number of each file. I find it odd that you got this far and you're stuck now. Is this someone else's code you are trying to edit?

Comment: If you are saving this in database, why not explicitly save the version number information, so you don't have to due string manipulation every time?

Comment: if you're never going to have non-numeric version numbers, e.g. `1.2beta`, then you can do a simple "replace everything that's not a digit/dot" regex, e.g. `$ver = preg_replace('/[0-9.]/', '', $text_version)`

Comment: Agreed, a regex is the way to go - but use the end-of-string anchor, something like '/(_Ver\s)([0-9\.]+)$/' to handle `1.2beta` (here $1 will contain '_Ver ' and $2 '0.1'

Comment: @degenerate - I was just wondering if there was an easier way then creating another function to handle every filename conversion.

Comment: @hikaru12 Put the `explode` function in your own function called `get_version_number($filename)` and return the version number -- then use the function in both places. Functions for small jobs are just as important as big ones :)

Comment: Thanks so much. Simple enough @degenerate

Comment: @symcbean - I went with your Regex but when I add the word beta it doesn't seem to find it when I labeled it `1.2beta` or `0.01beta`. I tried the following but this will only find the vernum or the word beta `[0-9\.]+|(beta)` I'm also running into an issue by modifying the variable `$updatedFileName` in the major version of the code and writing it like this `$updatedFileName2 = update_file_name_major( $fileName['name']);` I get the name of the file written as follows: Example: test_Ver 1.txt writes to the database as ttest_Ver 1.txt. It adds an extra letter.